# Как сместить разделитель через str_split или другую функцию?

Tags: php

**Дано:** 1947923939

**Через str_split получаю:** 194 792 393 9

**Надо:** 1 947 923 939

Если я неправильно сформулировал вопрос, буду признателен за реформулировку.

Comment: Использовать функцию `number_format()`.

Comment: забавы ради. `echo join(' ', array_map('strrev', array_reverse(str_split(strrev(1947923939), 3))));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например использовать функцию `number_format()`:

```
echo number_format(1947923939, 0, ', ', ' '); // 1 947 923 939
```

Либо через регулярные выражения, как пример:

```
echo preg_replace('/(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+$)/', '$1 ', 1947923939); // 1 947 923 939
```

https://3v4l.org/tSR7p